# Additivity of purity of random matrix products

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, random-matrices

Suppose $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with IID random entries drawn from $\mathcal{D}$ and $\sigma$ is the vector of its singular values. Define purity of $M$ as

$$\rho(M)=\frac{n \sum_i \sigma_i^4}{\left(\sum_i \sigma_i^2\right)^2}$$

Take square matrices $A$, $B$ with entries sampled IID from distributions $\mathcal{D}_1$, $\mathcal{D}_2$ respectively.
The following appears to [hold empirically](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-purity-of-matrix-products.nb) for standard normal $\mathcal{D}_1$ and symmetric uniform $\mathcal{D}_2$ and $n=1000$

$$\rho(AB)\approx \rho(A)+\rho(B)-1$$

Is this a well-known result? Any pointers to the literature appreciated!

Comment: What is $B$ here?

Comment: @IosifPinelis edited for clarity

Comment: So, are $A$ and $B$ independent? Also, did you try sampling for both $A$ and $B$ from the standard normal distribution (or for both $A$ and $B$ from a symmetric uniform distribution)?

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, $A$ and $B$ are independent. I also tried samping $A$, $B$ from the same distribution and it still holds. Purity of product of $A_1\ldots A_k$ is $k+1$ whether we use same distribution ([graph](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-purity-of-matrix-products.nb)) for $A_i$ or different. This works for Uniform(-1,1), Normal, breaks down for Cauchy.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm checking see if this follows from techniques in this [tutorial](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/473/1/012002/pdf)

Comment: @IosifPinelis OK this seems to be because for $X=$product of $k$ Ginibre matrices, S-Transform of $XX^T$ is $1/(1+z)^k$. This gives inverse MGF of $z/(1+z)^{k+1}$, use series reversion to find that first 2 moments are $1, k,\ldots$. Works for both symmetric uniform and Gaussian entries because they both follow circular law, hence same S-transform